# Error 404 NOT FOUND occurs when trying to GET from django

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

I am getting the 404 error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/$%7Bcategory_slug%7D/$%7Bproduct_slug%7D:1

my code for product/models.py:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files import File
from django.db import models

class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}/'

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added',)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.category.slug}/{self.slug}/'
    
    def get_image(self):
        if self.image:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.image.url
        return ''
    
    def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.image:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                self.save()

                return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return ''

    def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

        thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

        return thumbnail
```

the product page,product.vue code:

```
<template>
    <div class="page-product">
        <div class="column is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-9">
                <figure class="image mb-6">
                    <img v-bind:src="product.get_image">
                </figure>

                <h1 class="title">{{ product.name }}</h1>

                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-3">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Information</h2>

                <p><strong>Price: </strong>Ksh{{ product.price }}</p>
                <div class="field has-addons mt-6">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="number" class="input" min="1" v-model="quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                        <a class="button is-dark" @click="addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { toast } from 'bulma-toast'

export default {
    name: 'Product',
    data() {
        return {
            product: {},
            quantity: 1
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getProduct()
    },
    methods: {
        getProduct() {
            const category_slug = this.$route.params.category_slug
            const product_slug = this.$route.params.product_slug

            axios
                .get('/api/v1/products/${category_slug}/${product_slug}')
                .then(response => {
                    this.product = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        },
        addToCart() {
            if (isNaN(this.quantity) || this.quantity < 1) {
                this.quantity = 1
            }

            const item = {
                product: this.product,
                quantity: this.quantity
            }

            this.$store.commit('addToCart', item)

            toast({
                message: 'The product was added to the cart!',
                type: 'is-success',
                dismissible: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                duration: 2000,
                position: 'bottom-right',
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

my product/urls.py code is:

```
from django.urls import path

from product import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('latest-products/', views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
    path('products/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.ProductDetail.as_view()),
]
```

my main.js in for the vue app is :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router, axios).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Share please `ProductDetail`, because it's most likely not finding an object there.

Answer (score 0):

You make a request with "/api/v1/" in axios. Did you forget that inside Django URL patterns or "axios.defaults.baseURL"?

```
axios
  .get('/api/v1/products/${category_slug}/${product_slug}')
  .then(response => {
      this.product = response.data
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
  })
```